# getAbsolutePath() - cannot resolve method - Android studio

Tags: android

I'm starting and learning to write a file into SD card. However, I need some clarification because I  dont understand why I get the error at getAbsolutePath() (which is detected by Android studio).

```
public class AndroidFileIO implements FileIO {
  Context context;
  AssetManager assets;
  String externalStoragePath;

public AndroidFileIO( Context context ) {
  this.context = context;
  this.assets = context.getAssets();
  this.externalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageState().getAbsolutePath()
                  + File.separator;
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: use `getExternalStorageDirectory ()` instead of `getExternalStorageState()`

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
this.externalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageState().getAbsolutePath()
              + File.separator;
```

to

```
this.externalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
              + File.separator;
```

More info @

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

`public static String getExternalStorageState ()` // return type is string

```
Added in API level 1
Returns the current state of the primary "external" storage device
```

`public static File getExternalStorageDirectory ()`

```
Added in API level 1
Return the primary external storage directory
```

And look at the docs for `File`

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()

`public String getAbsolutePath ()`

```
Added in API level 1
Returns the absolute path of this file. An absolute path is a path that starts at a root of the file system. On Android, there is only one root: /.
```